# Secure many URLs with Symfony Voters

Tags: security, symfony

Is it possible to use voters like access control (`path: ^/project`)? 
To secure all pages (project/show, project/edit, project/create) at the same time?

Because it is annoying to secure each controller with the annotation `@Security("is_granted('view', project)")`...

Comment: Try to do it in a Kernel.request event.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#request-events-checking-types

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Security` on the Class annotation.

I never tried that yet, though, but from the docs

`You can also add a @Security annotation on a controller class.`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html